# Java swing GUI once checkbox selected

Tags: java, swing

Reeeealy need your help on java. I hava a frame1.java for three checkboxs and each of one correspond a JPanel in frame2.java. The panels will display in frame2 is determined by checkbox you selected in frame1. How to write the code? thanks.

Comment: Please write the code first and then others can help in case of any errors or improvement required.

Answer (score 3):

See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Check Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). It shows how to add an ItemListner to the check box.

Answer (score 0):

using the frame1 constructor create an object to the frame to and set its status to invisible
using `setVisible(false)` and also attach three panels to second frame and make them as invisible ,make your first frame visibility as true.
place three checkboxes and using their event handling(you can use ChangeListener),
for every checked event second frame visibility to true and also respective panel visibility
to true. place a ok button in the second frame.because when second frame is appears you cant perform check event on first frame.so write action event for button,so that when you cliked the ok button second frame goes to invisible.

sample:
[change listener example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoJCheckBoxEventswithaChangeListenerlistentoarmedpressedselectedorreleasedstate.htm)